# Is it possible to create two interdependent dynamic linked libraries?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I have been trying to do this for a few days (on windows). And getting errors like import library not found, unresolved symbols etc. I get that the problem is that when one library is being built the other's import library isn't present and vice versa. So due to this is it even possible to create such libraries? If yes than how? I haven't been able to find a way of doing this.

The answers here: [C++: How to create two interdependent shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260878/c-how-to-create-two-interdependent-shared-libraries)
suggest that it makes no sense to do so, but I want my project divided into parts and I want to be able to update one of them without having to recompile the whole project.

Comment: [It's possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/mutual-imports), but it's a pain, and it's not clear why one would ever want to do this.

Comment: Parts - good.  Circular dependencies bad.  If you want the real long term solution; it's go back to your design and fix it.

Comment: I don't really understand, normally the linking is not the most expensive part of the compilation right? I.e. if you divide your project in several `cpp`-files you can compile them to object files independently. These you finally link. The object files of the unchanged parts of your code you can simply reuse (provided that you system did not change).

Comment: @TomdeGeus I mostly work with visual studio's solutions/projects or qmake's subdirs, and have my modules divided into different projects rather than different cpp files/objects. How do i achieve something similar to what my question says?