# Allow mutual dependencies in Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I am trying to migrate a huge base of code from a custom in-house toolchain to Cmake. This code is comprised of lots of shared libraries and some executable.

Some of these libraries are interdependent. Let's take as examples Lib1 and Lib2, where Lib1 uses symbols from Lib2, and Lib2 uses symbols from Lib1.
In order to to create the Lib1 DLL, we need exported symbols from Lib2, which in turn need exported symbols from Lib1. Currently we resolved this by linking in two phases, as described here :  [Mutual Imports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/mutual-imports?view=vs-2019)
). This gives us the following steps :

1. Create lib1.lib and lib1.exp
   Create lib2.lib and lib2.exp
2. Create lib1.DLL using lib1.obj and lib2.lib/lib2.exp
   Create lib2.DLL using lib2.obj and lib1.lib/lib1.exp

I know that this is a code smell, but the code base is way too huge to try and correct all of these cycles. So I would like to get a similar result using Cmake. I did not find any way of doing this from the documentation, except using only custom commands which would completely defeat the purpose of this tool.

The legacy toolchain does the following calls :

```bsh
# compile sources
cl lib1\SRC\lib1help.cpp ... /Fo"build\cl\lib1.obj"
cl lib2\SRC\lib2help.cpp ... /Fo"build\cl\lib2.obj"

# create lib + exp symbols
lib /DEF build\cl\lib1.obj /OUT:build\link1\lib1.lib
lib /DEF build\cl\lib2.obj /OUT:build\link1\lib2.lib

# create mutual dependant dll using exp
link build\cl\lib1.obj build\link1\lib2.lib /DLL /OUT:build\link2\lib1.dll 
link build\cl\lib2.obj build\link1\lib1.lib /DLL /OUT:build\link2\lib2.dll
```

As of now I have the following CmakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(lib2 SHARED lib2/src/lib2help.cpp)
add_library(lib1 SHARED lib1/src/lib1help.cpp)

target_include_directories(lib1 PUBLIC lib1/include/)
target_compile_definitions(lib1 PRIVATE __LIB1)
target_link_libraries(lib1 PRIVATE lib2)

target_include_directories(lib2 PUBLIC lib2/include/)
target_compile_definitions(lib2 PRIVATE __LIB2)
target_link_libraries(lib2 PRIVATE lib1)
```

This gives me the following result :

```
[cmake] CMake Error: The inter-target dependency graph contains the following strongly connected component (cycle)  
[cmake]   "lib2" of type SHARED_LIBRARY  
[cmake]     depends on "lib1" (weak)  
[cmake]   "lib1" of type SHARED_LIBRARY  
[cmake]     depends on "lib2" (weak)
```

Do you guys know a way I could implement this using Cmake ?
For now I plan on only targeting windows systems, but a OS agnostic would be awesome !

Thanks

Comment: Create two targets for each lib - one `SHARED` and one `STATIC`?

Comment: CMake doesn't naturally support interdependent shared libraries. It can help you in the 1 and 3 steps of your workflow (creating static and shared libraries), but you need to perform step 2 manually, by using appropriate `add_custom_command` or `add_custom_target`. As for OS-agnostic way, you hardly can do it so. I fear linux's loader doesn't support interdependent shared libraries at all. See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260878/c-how-to-create-two-interdependent-shared-libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so fixated on making a SHARED library that I didn't explore the STATIC+SHARED way. Thanks to [@arrowd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637669/arrowd) and [@tsyvaref](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) for the suggestion.

I got it working using the following CmakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib1_obj OBJECT src/lib1help.cpp)
target_include_directories(lib1_obj PUBLIC include/)
target_include_directories(lib1_obj PRIVATE $<TARGET_PROPERTY:lib2_obj,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
target_compile_definitions(lib1_obj PRIVATE __LIB1)

add_library(lib1_static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib1_obj>)
target_link_libraries(lib1_static PUBLIC lib2_static)
set_target_properties(lib1_static PROPERTIES STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS "/DEF") 
set_target_properties(lib1_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME lib1)

add_library(lib1_shared SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib1_obj>)
target_link_libraries(lib1_shared PRIVATE lib1_static)
set_target_properties(lib1_shared PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME lib1)

add_library(lib1 ALIAS lib1_shared)
```

The exact same file is used for lib2, except of course switching names.
I am not sure this is the best way, but I am happy enough for now.
Here is what's happening :

- Compile sources into an OBJECT library
- Link the mutually dependants libs as static, with the "/DEF" to create export file
- Rename the static libs output to facilitate their usage for linker
- Link the shared library using .obj, .lib, and .exp previsouly created
- Rename the shared library dll to be used easier

Here we can see the content of each DLL using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) :
[image]